# Compare 2 vertex labelled directed graphs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Are there any standard algorithms that address the following:

> Compare 2 vertex labelled directed graphs and check for isomorphism

Comment: Your question is unclear, please elaborate and preferably add an example.

Comment: There are algorithms which check for isomorphism between 2 graphs with unlabelled vertices. But, are there any algorithms which check for isomorphism between 2 graphs with their vertices labelled?

Comment: @user3371307 : Does the isomorphism have to respect the labels? In other words are the graphs "1<-2->3" and "2<-1->3" isomorphic or not?

Comment: They are "Not isomorphic"

Comment: Then all you have to do is compare the adjacency matrices/lists and see if they are identical.